# Jquery: How to hide an element while it is in orther element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

how to hide a "cube-2" by click on "click-me" that its included by "cube-2"?
I made an event but it deleted all of my cube-2, I want to hide cube-2 one by one. Anyone can solve this? please help me.

```js
$('.cube-1').click(function name(params) {
    $('.cube-1').append('<div class="cube-2"><div class="click-me">click me to hide this cube</div></div>');
    // how to add event click on "click-me" to hide "cube-2"??
})
```

```css
.cube-1 {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    float: left;
    background: blue;
}
.cube-2 {
    margin-left: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    float: left;
    background: red;
}

.click-me {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background: white;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <div class="cube-1"></div>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an id to your cube-2 div and it's corresponding click-me anchor tag and remove only the div with that Id.

You may also want to check [Template string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

```
$('.cube-1').click(function name(e) {
    var cubeCounter = 1;
    if (e.target.className == "cube-1") {
        $('.cube-1').append(`<div class=cube-2 id=cube-${cubeCounter}><div class=click-me id=${cubeCounter}>click me to hide this cube</div></div>`);
        cubeCounter++;
    }
})

$(document).on('click', '.click-me', function name(e) {
    var cubeId = e.target.id;
    $(`#cube-${cubeId}`).remove();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to handle dyanamic click event of second cube and prevent click event of parent control, when child cube is clicked

```
$('.cube-1').click(function name(e) {

    if(e.target.className == "cube-1")
    {
      $('.cube-1').append('<div class="cube-2"><div class="click-me">click me to 
      hide this cube</div></div>');
    }

});

 $(document).on('click','.cube-2',function name(e) 
 {
      $(this).remove();
      // how to add event click on "click-me" to hide "cube-2"??
 })
```

Please check working demo [Link]

https://jsfiddle.net/2L3k5hcb/

Comment: This deletes all the cube-2 and hence doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: i appreciating your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to bind your click on div while you appending your cube-2.

Add your script as below-

$('.cube-1').on('click',function(event){
        $('.cube-1').append('click me to hide this cube');
    })
    function myFunction(param) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        $(param).remove();
    }

Answer (score 0):

you can use below method for dynamicly generated elements.

```js
$(document).on('click', '.click-me', function (e) {
    $(this).hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
$(document.body).on('click', '.cube-2', function (event) {
    $(this).hide();
});


$('.cube-1').click(function(event) {




 if(event.target.className =='cube-1')

    $('.cube-1').append('<div class="cube-2"><div class="click-me">click me to hide this cube</div></div>');
    // how to add event click on "click-me" to hide "cube-2"??
})
```

```css
.cube-1 {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    float: left;
    background: blue;
}
.cube-2 {
    margin-left: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    float: left;
    background: red;
}

.click-me {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cube-1"></div>
```